# WPF- Auto Resize the popup control

Tags: xaml, canvas, popup

I am New WPF. I have PopupControl below is XAML for that:-

```
<Popup Name="PopupRemark" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Left" HorizontalOffset="45"  VerticalOffset="-22"
                                            PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" 
                                            IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnInfo}"  StaysOpen="False"  >
                                        <Canvas Width="230" Height="200" Background="Transparent" >
                                            <Path x:Name="Container" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="#f2f6f7" Stroke="#A9A9A9" 
                                                        Data="M 230,40 L220,50 220,90 0,90 0,0 220,0 220,30 230,40">
                                                <Path.Effect>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="18" Color="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>
                                                </Path.Effect>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold"  FontFamily="Roboto" Content="Remark" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="25" Width="210" Text="{Binding Remark}" Foreground="#2c3e50" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrapwithoverflow" />
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </Popup>
```

Issue is, I want to set auto height & width for canvas or popup control so my popup will size as per content into it.I googled and knew that canvas should have fix height or width but is there any solution(Workaround) to make popup auto sizable.or how can add scroller into popup. It will be greatly appreciable

Thanks in advance

Comment: doesnt your popup already take only what it needs for that fixed size canvas? as for scrollviewer you can simply do this: <Scrollviewer Height="100"> *canvas here* </ScrollViewer>